# mTracks size is 0 I Do not know why retrieve returns null

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-realtime-database

**1- MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> mListItems = Arrays.asList("Hamaki","Amr Diab");
    private ArtistsAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Artist_list_view);

        mAdapter = new ArtistsAdapter(this, mListItems);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SoundActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Artist", mListItems.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

        });

    }

}
```

**2-Sound Activity:**

```
public class SoundActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new SoundFragment()).commit();
        }

    }
```

**3-Sound Fragment:**

```
public class SoundFragment extends Fragment {

    static SCTrackAdapter mAdapter;
    static DatabaseReference db;
    static FirebaseHelper helper;
    private TextView mSelectedTrackTitle;
    static ArrayList<Music> mTracks = new ArrayList<>();
    static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private ImageView mPlayerControl;
    static String Artist;
    static ListView listView;
    int currentTrack;
    private static String fileName;

    public SoundFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        new Fetchtracks().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sound, container, false);

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            Artist = intent.getStringExtra("Artist");
        }

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.track_list_view);
        mAdapter = new SCTrackAdapter(getActivity(), mTracks);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

**4- STrack Adapter:**

```
public class SCTrackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Music> mTracks;

    public SCTrackAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Music> tracks) {
        mContext = context;
        mTracks = tracks;
    }

    public void update_tracks(ArrayList<Music> list)
    {
        mTracks.clear();
        mTracks.addAll(list);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTracks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Music getItem(int position) {
        return mTracks.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.track_list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.track_title);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.titleTextView.setText(mTracks.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
    }

}
```

**5- Fetchtracks:**

```
public class Fetchtracks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Music>> {

@Override

protected ArrayList<Music> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Artist);
    helper = new FirebaseHelper(db);
    mTracks.addAll(helper.retrieve());
    Log.e("doInBackground: ",helper.retrieve()+"");
    return mTracks;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Music> list) {
    super.onPostExecute(list);

    Log.e("doInBackground: ",list.size()+"");
    mAdapter.update_tracks(list);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**6- FirebaseHelper**:

```
public class FirebaseHelper {

DatabaseReference db;
Boolean saved=null;
ArrayList<Music> A = new ArrayList<>();

public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
    this.db = db;
}
//WRITE

public Boolean save(Music m)
{
    if(m==null)
    {
        saved=false;
    }else
    {
        try
        {
           // db.child(Artist).push().setValue(m);
            saved=true;
        }catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved=false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}
//READ
public ArrayList<Music> retrieve()
{
    A.clear();
    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.e("onChildAdded: ", "1");
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.e("onChildAdded: ", "2");
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           // Log.e("onChildAdded: ", "3");
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           // Log.e("onChildAdded: ", "4");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           // Log.e("onChildAdded: ", "5");
        }
    });

    return A;
}
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
        Music m=new Music();

        m.setName(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
        m.setUrl(dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue().toString());
        A.add(m);
//            SoundFragment.mTracks.add(m);
//            Log.e("onFetch: ", SoundFragment.mTracks.size()+"");

}
```

}

**7- Music:**

```
public class Music {

    String name;
    String url;

    public Music() {

    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getURL() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you know that your mTracks is empty?
Did you try to log it for any values?
Also if the listView is empty, I'd suggest you to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` after the `addAll()` method in `doInBackground` in your asyncTask.

Comment: Also, have you edited the database rules in your firebase realtime database to be readable?
Because by default, you can not read or write from the firebase database until and unless you are authenticated

Comment: I tried to log mTracks value that size is 0, I have edited the database rules in my firebase realtime database to be readable.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at the code, but it seems to me that you are doing way too much of overhead work just to fetch data from your database.
For example in onChildAdded, you can simple pass your Music.class in the dataSnapshot and add the item directly from then and there.
Also you are using way too many static objects which is not at all good and  should be avoided.
Lastly, Firebase automatically does networks calls on a separate thread, so there is no need to use asynctask unless you are doing some heave work on callback.
Refer to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38507491/5471095

Answer (score -1):

no need to call this in onPostExecute() as it is only set

```
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: check this now! and what happens now?

Comment: when mTracks is coming null

Comment: @Tulsi if this is not an answer, you should continue it in the comment itself.

Comment: I thought this would do the job as setting an another adapter would certainly cause problems! here you downvoted an answer because it is incomplete! but let me tell you it is not incorrect @HarshitDwivedi